# Suggestion with JavaScript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I am developing a guess a number game. The user will guess a number between 1-10. At the start of the application will only show a input box where user will be able to write a number and a Guess button.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH1lw.jpg

As the guesses goes on the box will increase its size and go downwards. With every guess the box will be bigger.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz8Wv.jpg

I have figured out another way to do it but it is not working as I actually want it to work. Any suggestions, please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Guess the Number!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
#container{
border: thick double black;
padding: 1em;
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<fieldset>
<legend>Inputs</legend>
<label for="guess">Your Guess:</label>
<input type="text" id="guess" value="" />
<input type="button" onclick="yourGuess()" value="Guess" /> 
<input type="button" onclick="generateNumberToGuess(true)" value="New Game" /><br />
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="guesses" class="guesses">
<legend> Output </legend>
<textarea id="output" name="output" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
</fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function yourGuess() {
// You can store references to the value and the 
// guesses textarea in local function variables.
var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
var guesses = document.getElementById("output");

// First, if the guess is the same, just show the answer.
// Append onto the textarea the result.
if (guess == numToGuess) {
    guesses.value = guesses.value + "\r" + "You have guessed correctly! ("+guess+")  Press New Game     to play again!";
} else if(guess > 10) {
        guesses.value = guesses.value + "\r" + "Your guess is too high. Guess a number between 1-10!   ("+guess+")";

}else if (guess > numToGuess) {
    guesses.value = guesses.value + "\r" + "You guessing too high!("+guess+")";
} else {
    guesses.value = guesses.value + "\r" + "You guessing too low!("+guess+")";
}

}



// Randomly generate a number
function generateNumberToGuess(confirmIt) {
var guesses = document.getElementById("output");

// First, confirm this is what we want if the confirmIt
// argument was passed.
if (confirmIt && !confirm('Restart game with new number?')) {
    return;
}

guesses.value = '';
numToGuess = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
guesses.value = "Guess a number.\n";

// Don't forget to hide the new number.
document.getElementById('numberToGuess').value = '';
document.getElementById('cheatShow').style.display = 'none';
}


window.onload = function(){
generateNumberToGuess();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **but it is not working as I actually want it to work**..... so how do you actually want it to work?

Comment: Well, I dont want the output to look like how it is looking like right now, but as on the picture I have attached.

Comment: are you saying you are not satisfied with the styling?

Comment: Yes my friend, I just cannot figure out how to make it work like the picture I attached, How to extend the box with every guess...

Comment: All the functions are working well, but the result/output should look like the picture...

Comment: Go to codeacademy, learn CSS, make a JSFiddler for us, post it here so that we can help you. And your effect to make it bigger after a wrong answer, is not a CSS issue, it's a JQuery issue. You can't expect us to style everything for you. This is not what SO is for

Answer (score -1):

Alright I styled it for you. But I would suggest spending some time in a more "from the ground-up" tutorial in CSS. Codeacademy.com is a good place to start. My advise here is not to use `fieldset` Fieldsets are not supposed to be used as containers the way you used them. Get acquainted with the div layout. Also, the way you had some stuff formated kind of gave the feel that it came from a ASP.NET environment. Reason I say that is the way you constructed the buttons. ASP.NET developers have the bad habit to use a lot of inline style because the way the web controls are handled. Avoid this as much as possible.

Anyway, go to this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEqZBN)** You will find the styled code in there. Good luck

Comment: Thanks. But there is still a problem. Before any guess the div should include only the input, guesa and reatart game. With every guess the siv should be bigger. Hope u understand...